# Hide color tags and format tag contents in according color

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a text file with color tags, for example:
`foo <color=#c16e0d>bar</color> baz`

I would like the tag contents to be colored in #c16e0d and the tags hidden, so that the result is "foo **bar** baz", except `bar` not being bold, but colored in #c16e0d. 
I tried

`:syn region String start=/<color=#[0-9a-f]*>/ end=/<\/color>/ concealends`

which makes the tags and their contents pink, but doesn't conceal the tags themselves, even if I run the command in a JSON file where concealing works fine (`:set conceallevel=3`).

For the coloring I looked at the source of https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color, which seemed overly complex for my simple task.
There are only a few different colors for which I could specify individual syntax rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first thought I was looking at a bug, but re-reading `:help :syn-concealends`, the last sentence is of significance:

> The ends of a region can only be concealed separately
>   in this way when they have their own highlighting via "matchgroup"

Put in another way, `concealends` only becomes effective if you specify a `matchgroup=...`; I guess this is because of implementation reasons; concealing is linked to certain highlight groups.

---

So, to fix your example, use this:

```
:syn region myColorTag matchgroup=String start=/<color=#[0-9a-f]*>/ end=/<\/color>/ concealends
```

You're already aware of plugins that parse color information in a general way. I do agree with you that with a limited set of colors, it's better to just write individual syntax rules and highlight groups.

Comment: Thanks for figuring that out. My individual syntax rules now look like `:syn region g_c16e0d matchgroup=String start=/<color=#c16e0d>/ end=/<\/color>/ concealends` and the highlight rules like `:hi g_c16e0d guifg=#c16e0d`, which achieves my exact goal.